# Is it possible to deal with circular references in .net core 2 dependency injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0, circular-dependency

N-Tier design, I have `UserRepository` which does database stuff, `UserManager` which does business logic, and a Controller.

I make an `OrderManager` and `OrderRepository` for orders.

In my `UserManager`, I have a method such as `DoUserStuffThenAddAnOrder()`

This method will do some stuff related to Users, but then called `AddOrder()` on my `OrderManager`.

So I dependency inject `OrderManager` into my `UserManager` so it can call Order related methods.

But then I have the same problem in `OrderManager` where I want to `DoOrderStuffThenChangeAUser()`, so I DI a `UserManager` into `OrderManager`.

Then my DI breaks because of circular reference; creating an OrderManager requires injecting a UserManager into it, injecting a usermanager requires an ordermanager, etc etc to infinite.

Is there a solution for this? Perhaps a way to tell it to pass itself in as the parameter in the DI setup?

As a workaround I have created an `OrderManagerFactory` and a `UserManagerFactory` and created two overloaded constructors on each, the Controller making a new instance will DI an OrderManagerFactory, for example, which in the constructor will do `.GetOrderManager(this)` calling the overloaded constructor, and vica versa.

But having two constructors isn't very nice, and if I create more Managers then it will likely create a hellscape of injection and constructors.

Is there a neat solution to this? Other questions suggest that if you have this problem your software is architected incorrectly but it seems reasonable that SRP would dictate each manager doing its own thing and allowing them to call each other for business logic to be self-contained.

Here is an example:

```
public class UserManager {

    private IOrderManager _orderManager;

    public UserManager(IOrderManager orderManager)
    {
        _orderManager = orderManager;
    }

    public void DeleteUser(int userId) {

         if (_orderManager.GetOrdersForUser(userId).Count != 0) {
             throw new Exception("Cannot delete user while orders exist");
         }

         // Do a bunch of stuff connected with deleting a user

         // Send them a goodbye e-mail
         EmailUser(123, "Goodbye");

    }

    public void EmailUser(int userId, string message)
    {
        var userMail = _repository.GetUser(userId).EmailAddress;
        _emailSomething.Send(userMail, message);
    }
}
```

And

```
public class OrderManager {

    private IUserManager _userManager;

    public OrderManager(IUserManager userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public IEnumerable<OrderDto> GetOrdersForUser(int userId)
    {
        return Map(_repo.GetOrdersForUserId(userId));
    }

    public void CancelOrder(int orderId)
    {
        var userId = _repo.GetOrder(orderId).UserId;

        // Cancel order
        var user = _userManager.GetUserById(userId);

        _userManager.EmailUser(userId, "Hello " + user.Name + ", your order has been cancelled");
    }
}
```

This is impossible as neither IOrderManager nor IUserManager can be injected in without a circular reference error.

Comment: It's impossible to `new` these objects up without the use of an intermediate abstraction (such as factory, `Lazy` etc)

Comment: Do you think that the fundamental design is wrong? One option would be instead of `UserManager>OrderManager>OrderRepository` to simply inject the repository, and do `UserManager>OrderRepository`. But there's a risk you'd cut out or have to duplicate some business logic doing that.

Comment: The design seems more complicated than it needs to be and IMO a bit of duplication is better than managing circular dependencies.

Comment: The problem is that you're bleeding between domains. One thing or the other should operate on both, not both on both, i.e. you need to determine which is your aggregrate for this particular subdomain.

Comment: The issues is having to duplicate blocks of logic, if you have a CreateUser method on your UserManager, and then you have an OrderManager that does some stuff and then creates a user, you need to copy that big block of code into your OrderManager method. Maybe a ServiceLocator pattern is better instead of dependency injection...

Comment: Cyclic dependencies are often caused by Single Responsibility Principle violations. Splitting up your classes into smaller, more-focussed classes might very well fix your problems.

Comment: I don't know how you can split it up further, if `UserManager` has a `SendEmailToUser()` method, you might want to invoke that in your `OrderManager` when an order is done, likewise if a user is deleted you might want to call `CancelAllOrders()` on your `OrderManager`. I can't see how you can simplify it so they don't need to talk to each other without something a bit hacky.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this problem @NibblyPig?

Comment: I am afraid I did not

Comment: There is a nuget package to solve this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConnectingApps.SmartInject

Answer (score 1):

Your classes sound like they're doing too much. The solution is to refactor your code using a more SOLID approach. DI works absolutely fine, but the fact that you're having problems indicates a problem in your approach, and its an indicator that you need to rethink - thats one of the purposes of the whole pattern

Comment: The problem is it is SOLID to follow SRP by putting User stuff in the User class, and Order stuff in the Order class, but when they both need to call each other, that's where the whole thing breaks down. It's the same as MVC itself, sometimes a controller will redirect to another controller, and sometimes that controller will redirect to the original controller, but controllers aren't dependency injected into each other, we can just route to a URL and the framework will automatically sort it out for us. So I'm thinking of having a singleton ManagerManager with the managers inside it.

Comment: Avoid the singleton as much as possible. Its another "ServiceLocator" type anti-pattern.. By far the easiest solution is to move the common methods from both Orders and Users out into different classes, and then only inject the ones you need into your Orders and Users classes. Rinse and repeat until your cyclic dependency disappears.. Thats the "correct" way to tackle the problem

Comment: You'd end up pulling the entire class out though, you could call almost any user function from your order manager, even something like `GetUserById` so you can grab their name or whatever. And vica versa, `GetOrdersForUser()` to display a count or whatever.

Comment: Can you update your question with some sample code to make it easier to visualise? It might make it easier for me to make my point too

Comment: "follow SRP by putting User stuff in the User class, and Order stuff in the Order class." I'm afraid you misunderstood the SRP. Putting "all user stuff in one class" is certainly *not* an implementation of the Single Responsibility Principle.