# A possible circular dependency with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, circular-dependency, clean-architecture

I'm using [this](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture) template as my base project. I would like to set a custom time zone that is user defined hence it is stored in the database.

The following is my failed attempt. Well, I tried many different approaches in vein. I hope that someone will be able to give me a right direction here.

```
namespace MyApp.Infrastructure.Services;

public class DateTimeService : IDateTime
{
    private readonly IAppDefaultServices _appDefaultServices;
    public DateTimeService(IAppDefaultServices appDefaultServices)
    {
        _appDefaultServices = appDefaultServices;
    }
    public DateTime Now()
    {
        DateTime utcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        TimeZoneInfo defaultZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(_appDefaultServices.DefaultTimeZone);
        DateTime appDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, defaultZone);
        return appDateTime;
    }
}

namespace MyApp.Application.Common.Interfaces;

public interface IDateTime
{
    DateTime Now();
}


namespace MyApp.Infrastructure.Services;

public class AppDefaultServices : IAppDefaultServices
{
    private readonly IApplicationDbContext _context;
    public AppDefaultServices(IApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    private AppDefault _appDefault => _context.AppDefaults.First();

    public string DefaultTimeZone => _appDefault.TimeZoneId == null ? "Some Standard Time" : _appDefault.TimeZoneId;

}

namespace MyApp.Application.Common.Interfaces;
public interface IAppDefaultServices
{
    public string DefaultTimeZone { get; }
}

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public static class ConfigureServices
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IAppDefaultServices, AppDefaultServices>();
        services.AddTransient<IDateTime, DateTimeService>();
    }
}
```

When I tried to run the application in Visual Studio, I get no errors but I can see the following message in thread window.

> The maximum number of stack frames supported by Visual Studio has been exceeded.

Please note that `DateTimeService` is being used in `MyApp.Infrastructure.Persistence.Interceptors.AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor` which is part of `ApplicationDbContext`

I really appreciate it if anyone could please shed a light here.

Based on Steve's comment below, I'm posting a minimal code to reproduce the issue.

```
namespace MyApp.Infrastructure.Persistence;

public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    private readonly AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor _auditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor;

    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions,
        AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor auditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor) 
        : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {
        _auditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor = auditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(_auditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor);
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

`Interceptor` code below...

```
namespace MyApp.Infrastructure.Persistence.Interceptors;
    
public class AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor : SaveChangesInterceptor
{
    private readonly IDateTime _dateTime;

    public AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor(
        IDateTime dateTime)
    {
        _dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public override InterceptionResult<int> SavingChanges(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result)
    {
        UpdateEntities(eventData.Context);

        return base.SavingChanges(eventData, result);
    }

    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        UpdateEntities(eventData.Context);

        return base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
    }

    public void UpdateEntities(DbContext? context)
    {
        if (context == null) return;

        foreach (var entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseAuditableEntity>())
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                entry.Entity.Created = _dateTime.Now();
            } 

            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added || entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                entry.Entity.LastModified = _dateTime.Now();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The amount of code you posted shows this isn't very "clean". *Remove* all this code and write *only* what's needed for the application to work. Hint: none of this code is relevant.

Comment: I apologize if I may be missing relevant code. but when I remove `AppDefaultServices` from ref. from `DateTimeService`, the application starts running. so I guess the code posted is somewhat relevant to the issue?

Comment: You don't have to worry about timezones if you use `DateTimeOffset` internally. The timezone is needed only when you need to convert to local time eg for display. At this point the timezone is configuration. If you want to have a single timezone for the entire application, that's a configuration setting. If you want to display using the *client's* timezone, the only safe way is to sent the ISO8601 datetime to the client and render it using Javascript. Browsers aren't required to send the timezone to the server so there's no other way to know the actual timezone

Comment: `is somewhat relevant to the issue` no it's not. You don't need 100 lines of code to display local time. Nor do you need 100 interfaces. `Clean Architecture` is a brand name, not a statement of fact.

Comment: `AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor` sounds important, but not included in your code. Anways, you have options, you can change to `services.AddSingleton` and instantiate before finishing configuring services. You can also create a deferred execution service, which is a bit more complicated than a single comment can described, but something like `services.AddTransient<Func<ApplicationConfiguration>>(serviceProvider => GetApplicationConfiguration);`  (with method signature `public abstract ApplicationConfiguration GetApplicationConfiguration();` )

Comment: If you want a fixed timezone per authenticate user that's again configuration, only this time it's part of the user's profile. Which of the three scenarios are you trying to implement? Fixed timezone ? Client timezone? User timezone? No matter the case, you only need a *single* service. That service should use either `IConfiguration` or the user profile to retrieve the timezone it needs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Unfortunately, the question is about dependency injection but not about time zones. can we please focus on the issue than time zones. I would post a different question if I wanted to know more about setting time zones. Thanks!

Comment: @BurnsBA, I've already tried `AddSingleton` but it didn't work either. I will try your second option though I didn't understand the concept entirely. I guess I need to do some research. `AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor` already in the git repo that I linked so I didn't post it here again.

Comment: @ecasper unfortunately, it's the opposite. You won't be able to solve the problem until you simplify the code and eliminate most of it. You are looking at *interceptors* to just get a local time! Which could just as easily be a `DateTimeOffset` ! The code is already unreadable and unmaintainable, which is why you posted a question. [This is how ASP.NET Core libraries handle the system clock](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Middleware/ResponseCaching/src/ResponseCachingOptions.cs#L35). That's more than enough to create audit entries in EF Core

Comment: ASP.NET Core and hence your own application already uses `ISystemClock` with a default implementation that returns  `DateTime.UtcNow`. That's good enough for EF Core auditing too. Using local time for audit entries is a *bad* idea. Offsets change due to daylight savings. Machines on different timezones or with different settings even in the same data center will have different local times. Their offsets may be updated at different times. That's why people use either UTC or the full ISO8601 including the offset. This is the only way you can match logs among different systems and services.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `Using local time for audit entries is a bad idea` I totally agreed but I would like to show tenant specific time for other date time entities such as when the order is created, when a meal is prepared, etc…I should simply use system date time for audit entries and then I should be able to solve the circular dependency issue by removing `DateTimeServices` dependency from DbContext. I’m also planning to load all app defaults in IOptions.

Comment: There is no cyclic dependency in the code you shared. That means that the issue is not reproducible. Please post a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: @Steven, I have just updated the question with `ApplicationDbContext` code and `AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor`, thanks!

Comment: Using the code you posted, you should be able to identify the cycle yourself. The cycle goes from DateTimeService to AppDefaultServices to ApplicationDbContext to AuditableEntitySaveChangesInterceptor back to DateTimeService.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043031/is-it-possible-to-deal-with-circular-references-in-net-core-2-dependency-inject

Comment: @Steven, thanks for your inputs. I'm aware of the cycle but I couldn't find a way to solve the circular dependency.

Comment: See [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67725031/circular-dependency-with-two-depending-services). It contains a question for a very similar problem, and a long answer explaining what the underlying problem is and how to refactor away from that.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67725031/circular-dependency-with-two-depending-services

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following solutions to refactor your way out of this cyclic dependency:

- Change `DateTimeService` to always return `UtcNow`. This prevents it needing to load the time zone and depend on `IAppDefaultServices`
- Consider loading the default time zone once at startup. This allows the `DateTimeService` to be injected with that pre-loaded time zone and prevent it from depending on `IAppDefaultServices`.
- Consider changing `AppDefaultServices` such that it doesn't depend on `IApplicationDbContext`, but instead depends on a second `DbContext` that solely allows accessing the `AppDefaults` in a read-only fashion. This new read-only `DbContext` will not need the interceptor, as it only adds behavior when mutating data.
- If, after applying the previous option, `AppDefaultServices` still requires the `IApplicationDbContext` dependency, consider splitting the `AppDefaultServices` into multiple classes with multiple interfaces, such that the new interface only contains the `DefaultTimeZone` property. This allows its implementation to solely contain a dependency on the 'AppDefaultsDbContext'.

Comment: Thanks for your time and assistance. 1. As someone else mentioned in the comment above, it is not an ideal way to set local time for audit entries. But in my case, it is a multi-tenant app and each tenant has its own db. so it would be much convenient to set a tenant specific time-zone for audit entries than using system time. 2. Since time-zone is user-defined, the app does not know the setting at Startup. 3. A separate DbContext is an option and thanks for letting me know. 4. I still prefer the last option in your list.  I tried many ways but still couldn't figure out a way for this.

Comment: Are you in position to provide me with a link/any source that explains your fourth option? much appreciated!

Comment: @ecasper: The fourth option is similar to the solution I gave in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67725031/circular-dependency-with-two-depending-services), which in turn is similar to the solution I give in [section 6.3](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-6/259) of [my book](https://cuttingedge.it/book).